# Paying bill for aveirah already done

Tags: halacha, money, transactions, sin, shlichus-agency

Is one allowed to pay a service fee for an aveirah which someone else has already done, in order to get some other good or service now? The case I had in mind is an animal adoption where the agency charges a fee for neutering already performed.

Comment: To understand the case: do they perform the procedure anyway on all animals in their care, or only on animals that are about to be adopted?

Comment: All animals; it's a done deal, and they are passing on the fee to the adopter.

Comment: Is neutering animals an aveirah for Gentiles?

Comment: @Shemmy it's a good question, but assume for here that the seller is a Jew.

Answer (score 2):

Paying for an Aveira that was already done, is probably not a problem - especially in this case where you did not request the Aveira to be done.

In [הלכות איסורי מזבח פרק ד:יב](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/8404.htm) the Rambam states that if you pay a harlot after the fact, the payment does not have the status of Ethnan and can be used as a Korban. This is true even if you agreed on a price and only sent the animal later, as Yehuda did (or tried to do) with Tamar.

Comment: Nice find, and +1, but I'm not sure the lack of applicability of _hilchos esnan_ implies that it's *permissible*.

Comment: @msh210 yes, but it's the act that's impermissible, not the payment - no? I would think even more so with the animal, since the payment does not degrade the act any more, as opposed to the zenus.